# Why is launchd saying "service already loaded" but "launchctl list" doesn't show the service?

Tags: launchd

I created the configuration files in  ~/Library/LaunchAgents

When I attempted to load the plist, I got the message that the service was already loaded.

```
launchctl load ~/LaunchAgents/hosts_Blocksites_AM.plist  
/Users/bryan/LaunchAgents/hosts_Blocksites_AM.plist: service already loaded
```

When I attempted to find the Launchd agent nothing was returned.

```
$ sudo launchctl list | grep hosts_Blocksites_AM.plist
```

EDIT: fixed typo where I had:
    launchctl load ~/LaunchAgents/hosts_unBlocksites_AM.plist

Comment: Try simplifying your `grep` statement and using the `-i` option in case you don't have the case correct (no pun intended):  `| grep -i blocksites`

Answer (score 2):

It's possibly because you grep'ed for a different file than you tried to load (hosts_**un**Blocksites_AM.plist vs. hosts_Blocksites_AM.plist), but also note that root has its own list of launch agents and when you run `sudo launchctl list` you will see root's list, which is different from `launchctl list` which will show yours.

So this should work (depending on what you're trying to do in your launch agent):

```
launchctl list | grep Blocksites
launchctl load ~/LaunchAgents/hosts_unBlocksites_AM.plist
```

If needed, run both as sudo (not just one of them).

Comment: That was a typo. I actually have hosts_unBlocksites_AM.plist and    hosts_Blocksites_AM.plist    Loaded with launchctl and neither show up in the:          launchctl list | grep -i blocksites

Comment: Check what you used for the Label string in your plist file. This is the string that is printed from `launchctl list`. Assuming standard formatting of the plist file, then `grep -A 1 Label ~/LaunchAgents/hosts_Blocksites_AM.plist` will show the Label string you used.

Answer (score 0):

Take off the `.plist`.

```
$ sudo launchctl list | grep hosts_Blocksites_AM
```